# Javascript POST to PHP works locally, fails externally

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, http-post

This is really simple code I have, it works on my site (if link to php is just "/phpcode.php", but fails to retrieve data if I put the javascript request on the other site and call full link.
I am using godaddy.
I am beginner and have no freaking idea where to look for solution or troubleshoot it.

This is PHP side (full code of phpcode.php):

```html
<?php 
$val = 'apple'; 
echo json_encode($val);
?>
```

And here is javascript request:

```js
 $.post(
      "http://website.com/phpcode.php",function(data){
       alert(data);
    },
      "json");
```

And here is full code of the javascript page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){  
       $.post(
  "http://website.com/phpcode.php",function(data){
   alert(data);
},
  "json");
        });
      });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>TEST POST</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post the http result (200, 404, 500) including the body (some errer message that lives somewhere.. or not).

Comment: Where is the HTML located? Is it hosted in godaddy or is it saved locally on your ?computer?

Comment: We will need the error message server is throwing to know what is happening. But i guess this is a CORS issue, in which case should be resolved by changing http to https.

Comment: Check your console for errors.

Comment: Ok guys, so based on @Stefan suggestion I went to chrome inspect and checked the response. The response is there and it is correct, but the function(data){alert(data); part does not bring it to the screen, testing more.

Comment: Try removing the following: , "json"

Answer (score 0):

This could be something causing the error. Add the line

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

after `<?php` in `phpcode.php`, this would make your code:

```
<?php 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    $val = 'apple'; 
    echo json_encode($val);
?>
```

In future, you'll be more likely to get a better answer from your question if you include any error messages / warnings that can be seen. You can often see these in the javascript console. `[ctrl] + [shift] + [i]` in chrome and then go to the `console` tab.

Answer (score 0):

ok guys, it is solved. 
1st issue was that php code was put into http: site and calls were made from https: sites.
2nd - the particular site could not do alert(data), but response was there. Thank you @stefan for reminding to check responses. Solved it with an extra variable.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: FYI : Can use a *protocol relative* url for this. `$.post("//website.com/phpcode.php"`. Browser will use same protocol page is using